# How to convert to datetime object?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I have dates stored in this format (column one of my data)

```
> tmp[[1]]
# YYYYMMDD
19980102
```

And I have time store in this format (column two of my data)

```
> tmp[[2]]
#HHMM
0930
```

I was wondering how I could get this stored as a date-time format in R. I have tried using:

```
as.POSIXlt(paste(tmp[[1]], tmp[[2]]), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```

but my output is a bunch of `NA`'s

```
NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Your main problem is the incorrect use of the `%S` format specifier on the end of the format string, when there are no actual seconds digits in the time field. Also, I changed `paste()` to `paste0()` and removed the space in the format string, although that's insignificant.

```
tmp <- data.frame(date='19980102', time='0930', stringsAsFactors=F );
as.POSIXlt(paste0(tmp$date,tmp$time), format='%Y%m%d%H%M' );
## [1] "1998-01-02 09:30:00 EST"
```